# How does range-v3's `partial_sum` not contradict non-owning reference semantics?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Consider [How do I write a range pipeline that uses temporary containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820639/how-do-i-write-a-range-pipeline-that-uses-temporary-containers). The question is how to build a view transforming each element `T` using some given function

```
std::vector<T> f(T t);
```

while complying with [the restriction](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/)  (borrowing from the top answer there) that

> A view is a lightweight wrapper that presents a view of an underlying sequence of elements in some custom way without mutating or copying it. Views are cheap to create and copy, and have non-owning reference semantics.

Basically, all answers there seem to agree that, due to this restriction, it can't be done via a view.

---

I don't understand how this fits in with the library supporting [`partial_sum`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/partial_sum.hpp).

Consider the following glorified integer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

struct glorified_int {
    explicit glorified_int(int i) : m_i{std::make_shared<int>(i)} {}
    operator int() const { return *m_i; }
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_i;
};

glorified_int operator+(const glorified_int &lhs, const glorified_int &rhs) {
    glorified_int ret{(int)lhs + (int)rhs};
    return ret;
}
```

It basically just wraps up an `int` in a class storing it in an `std::shared_ptr`, allowing to initialize, extract, and add. W.r.t. non-owning reference semantics, I can't see the fundamental difference between it and a container such as `std::vector`.

Range doesn't seem to have a problem applying `partial_sum` to this, though:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<glorified_int> vi{ glorified_int{1}, glorified_int{2} };
    for(const auto &ps: vi | view::partial_sum())
        std::cout << ps << std::endl;
```

Prints out

```
$ ./a.out
1 
3
```

Isn't (the glorified integer of) 3 a temporary here? It's certainly not part of the original sequence. Also, a partial sum is a stateful transformation, obviously, so how can range guarantee that

> Views are cheap to create and copy, and have non-owning reference semantics.

The view is as expensive to copy as the accumulation object.

Note that there's also no problem to chain this further (i.e., it is not an action):

```
    vi | view::partial_sum() | view::take(10);
```

What is the difference, then?

---

**Full Code**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

struct glorified_int {
    explicit glorified_int(int i) : m_i{std::make_shared<int>(i)} {}
    operator int() const { return *m_i; }
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_i;
};

glorified_int operator+(const glorified_int &lhs, const glorified_int &rhs) {
    glorified_int ret{(int)lhs + (int)rhs};
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<glorified_int> vi{ glorified_int{1}, glorified_int{2} };
    for(const auto &ps: vi | view::partial_sum())
        std::cout << ps << std::endl;
    vi | view::partial_sum() | view::take(10);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes a view a view is that it doesn't take or require ownership of, copy, or modify any of the elements of the input range. But a view isn't required to have no state whatsoever. Even `take()` or `filter()` have *some* state (a counter and a predicate, respectively).

In this specific case, `partial_sum` doesn't have to own any of the elements of the input range. That's the input range's job. It also doesn't need to copy or modify them. It merely needs to keep track of its own state - the running sum (an `optional<glorified_int>`) and the binary function doing the summing (a `plus`). It owns one of its own objects, but that object exists outside of the input range entirely. That still makes it a view, just a stateful one.

You write:

> The view is as expensive to copy as the accumulation object.

This is true. But that's also true of many views. `transform()` is as expensive to copy as the function we're using to transform the view, maybe you have an enormous stateful, expensive, memory-allocating monstrosity.

When Eric writes about cheap to create and copy, I believe he means in the context of creating and copying the entire input range to produce a new range. While `partial_sum()` needs to keep the running sum, which in your case isn't cheap since that element needs allocation, that's still far cheaper than writing an action-based `partial_sum`:

```
// cheap version
for(const auto &ps: vi | view::partial_sum()) { ... }

// expensive version
std::vector<glorified_int> partial_sums;
if (!vi.empty()) {
    auto it = vi.begin();
    partial_sums.emplace_back(*it++);
    for (; it != vi.end(); ++it) {
        partial_sums.emplace_back(*it + partial_sums.back());
    }
}
for (const auto &ps : partial_sums) { ... }
```

We obviously don't need the entire `partial_sums` vector to do what we want (if we did need it, well, no way around that). The view offers us a cheap way to, well, view the partial sums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the same analogy, though, why couldn't the state in the aforementioned question be the vector formed by applying the function to the dereferenced iterator? In other words, why is the accumulation not considered an owned temporary, but the result of applying a function to a dereferenced iterator considered the opposite?

Comment: @AmiTavory Because a hypothetical `view::join()` would have to take ownership of the entire input range in order to pass it forward correctly.

Comment: Thanks again. Am starting to vaguely see what you mean. Will read the source of join (which I skipped) and [this](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/442).

Comment: Great answer. To clarify, "Cheap" in the context of views means "O(1) with respect to the length of the range being viewed."

Comment: somewhat related: [github/range-v3/issues/92: The current single_view should be an action not a view](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/92), Eric's answer: "The real distinction is that copying and assigning ranges should be O(1); that is, their complexity should not depend on the number of elements in the range"

Comment: If the state of a partial sum is one number (`sum_` in the [implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/partial_sum.hpp)), this implies an O(N) sweep from the beginning to the required position (a pipe to `view::reverse` will be O(N^2), and so on). How is this expressed in the range concepts? Something like `partial_sum` is forward iterable? Is it possible to use a `std::vector<T>` or a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` (and thus gain random access at the cost of an increased effort at creation) without missing the requirements for a range?