# Convert std::vector<string> to just a std::string in C++20 using std::views

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring, range-v3

I am trying to convert a vector to a string and join with C++20(MSVC on visual studio 19 v142, c++latest).

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = { "1s","2s" };
auto view1 = strings | std::views::transform([](std::string num) {return std::format("{} ", num); }); // okay
auto view2 = strings | std::views::join; // okay
auto view3 = strings | std::views::transform([](std::string num) {return std::format("{} ", num); }) | std::views::join; // Compiler error  
//error C2678: binary '|': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,_Ty>' "
```

I know I can do it elegantly with `actions` in range-v3, but I am not supposed to use it.

Is there a way to do it, by just using C++20 standard library?

Comment: When a program fails to compile, usually the compiler tells you why. Did you read the diagnostic message?

Comment: The example program doesn't seem to match the question. The program converts integer to strings; not a vector to a string.

Comment: AFAIK `std::format` is not supported yet by clang or gcc. And I think msvc has some problems with ranges.

Comment: MSVC doesn't implement [P2328](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2328r1.html) yet.

Comment: Demo when dropping std::format: https://godbolt.org/z/xThqaY6Yd

Comment: @eerorika I looked at the compiler error, and I know it will not work. I would like to know if there is some workaround other than using range-v3 library.

Comment: @SumitJha You knowing why it will not work isn't very useful for us. If you don't tell us why your program won't work, then how do you expect us to tell you how to work around it?

Comment: @SumitJha you have forgotten to write which compiler you are using (probably msvc) its version, and platform. Note that providing error logs is good practice in general. "Doesn't work" is not a description of a problem, compiler logs are.

Comment: @MarekR I am using MSVC c++latest and it supports format but the problem is not with format. I have updated the example. I am sorry, I will update the compiler.

Comment: @Barry I am able to use std::views::join  with MSVC, I not sure what you meant sorry.

Comment: Please [edit] your question when adding vital information, so future reader do not have to go through comments to have full picture.

Comment: @SumitJha note I written that gcc and clang do not support `std::format` and msvc do not support ranges join yet as Barry point out. So there is not compiler where your code works. C++20 is still to fresh to be used.

Comment: @MarekR I didn't say MSVC doesn't support `join`. I said specifically that it doesn't implement *that paper*.

Comment: @Barry sorry wrong wording from my side.

Comment: @Barry Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original design of `views::join`, it didn't just join *any* range of ranges, it had to be a range of reference to ranges.

This worked:

```cpp
auto view2 = strings | views::join; // okay
```

Because `strings` is a range of `string&` (which is a reference to a range).

But this did not:

```cpp
auto view3 = strings | views::transform([](std::string num) {
                           return std::format("{} ", num)
                       })
                     | views::join; // Compiler error
```

because now we're `join`ing a range of `string` (specifically, prvalue strings, which is what your function returns). That violated the constraints. range-v3's `views::join` has the same constraint.

---

However, it is a fairly [common use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36820639/2069064) to be able to do this. So a recent defect against C++20 was to change the design of `views::join` to allow it to join *any* range of ranges. That's [P2328](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2328r1.html). libstdc++ (gcc's standard library) already implements this, MSVC does not yet, nor does range-v3 (though I have a [PR open](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/1655)). So the official C++20 answer is: what you're doing is correct, your library just hasn't implemented it yet.

---

Now, the range-v3 answer is to introduce a caching layer:

```cpp
auto view3 = strings | rv::transform([](std::string num) {
                           return std::format("{} ", num)
                       })
                     | rv::cache1
                     | rv::join;
```

What `cache1` does is cache one element at a time, which turns our range of prvalue `string` into a range of lvalue `string` such that `join` can successfully join it. The P2328 design is to basically incorporate this internally into `join` itself so that you don't have to do it manually. But until that happens, you can do the above using range-v3. There is no `cache1` in C++20 and won't be in C++23 either.

Or you can use [Casey's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810436/2069064). But also don't.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why is `cache1` called `cache1` instead of `cache`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I dunno. It `cache`s `1` element.

Comment: @Barry why no cache1 in C++23? Too low level/unfriendly for "normal" users?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The main motivation for it was making this case work, but we didn't need it for that. And also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2328r1.html#motivation